# SSO breaks sometimes

Tags: single-sign-on, identity

I use ASP.MVC as identity provider and integrated salesforce page as iframe so that customers get seamless flow. It works first time the page is openned after user logs into MVC site. But when they take action inside that page, they get an error page, if user presses back button error goes away and page works and navigates without any problems.

One possible reason is that I am not on https, if thats true why does the page work after navigating back?

please help

Comment: @metadaddy where are you, I need your help :)

Comment: It appears that this is not related to https But something related to Antiforgery token

Comment: Would you mind elaborating, and if possible explain how you were able to resolve this ? That could be useful for others with similar problems in the future.

Comment: @Sdry actually this is not a right way because I disabled Antiforgery token which is a security concern. Still waiting for someone that knows the real solution.

Comment: Maby this than, is better put as update to your question  elaborating, rather than as an answer ?

Comment: @tsadigov, please add this as an edit or comment on the original question and explain why you think it is related to the antiforgery token.

Comment: What kind of error page do they see?